# How to groupby datetime + / - one minute?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with my order executions on the stock exchange. In most cases, I receive partial fills of my buy order. All order executions in the same second. Mostly.

So I can use groupby to get an overview of my trades. However, sometimes the partial order executions aren't exactly in the same second. And that's where my problem is coming from.

How do i grab all order confirmations in a timespan of 2 minutes, to ignore small differences in time?

This is for example my input

```
2019-09-17 18:30:46  23.5600  100.0   BOT   2356.0000
2019-09-17 18:30:47  23.5600   82.0   BOT   1931.9200
2019-09-17 18:30:47  23.5600  100.0   BOT   2356.0000
2019-09-17 18:30:47  23.5600  100.0   BOT   2356.0000
2019-09-17 18:30:47  23.5600  100.0   BOT   2356.0000
2019-09-17 18:30:47  23.5600  100.0   BOT   2356.0000
2019-09-17 18:30:47  23.5600  100.0   BOT   2356.0000
2019-09-17 18:30:47  23.5600  100.0   BOT   2356.0000
```

And I want it to get to look like this below, but that first line on 18:30:46 is creating a mess.

```
2019-09-17 18:30:47  23.560000  782.0  18423.9200
```

My code is extremely simple.

```
tradesum = tradeoverview.groupby(tradeoverview.index).sum()
```

How could I solve this issue? Maybe I can resample the df to 2-minute time intervals? But then I still run the risk of orders being split exactly on both sides of the interval.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `resample` method to basically group your data based on **its datetime index** for however many seconds or minutes (or other units of time). Here I passed `'2s'`to sample every 2 seconds, you could pass `'1m'` to sample at every minute, etc.

```
df.resample('2s').agg({'c1': 'max',
                       'c2': 'sum',
                       'c3': 'max',
                       'c4': 'sum'
                      })
```

assuming the column names are `dt, c1, c2, c3, c4`

```
                        c1   c2   c3        c4
dt                                            
2019-09-17 18:30:46  23.56  782  BOT  18423.92
```

Comment: But this doesn't quite fix the issue raised in the question. with a `1m` resample you still draw an arbitrary boundary between '2010-01-01 00:01:59' and '2010-01-01 00:02:01', despite them being 2 seconds apart.

Comment: It did the trick. Resampled dataframe with ('360s') and everything is broken down in 6 minute intervals. Only issue was 95% of the intervals were empty, but of course filtering out the data with trade details is easy.